# Loading data into .txt file with fixed length ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a task to create SSIS package to load data into .txt file as below

Have one table ex: employees

Have two SQL statements:

```
select emp_no,birth_date,first_name from employees
where emp_no in (10001,10002,10003,10004);
Result: (Fixed Lengths as Follows emp_No=5,Birth_date=10,First_Name=10, Total Length: 25)
10001   1953-09-02  abc
10002   1964-06-02  def
10003   1959-12-03  ghi
10004   1954-05-01  jkl
```

Second Statement:

```
select emp_no,last_name,gender,hire_date from employees
where emp_no in (10001,10002,10003,10004);
Result: (Fixed Lengths as follows emp_No=5,lastname=9,gender=1,hire_date=10, Total Length: 25)
10001   Abcdef      M   1986-06-26
10002   Bcdefghi    F   1985-11-21
10003   Cdefghijk   M   1986-08-28
10004   Defgh       M   1986-12-01
```

I have to create a package to get the data as below

```
100011953-09-02abc
10001Abcdef   M1986-06-26
100021964-06-02def
10002Bcdefghi F1985-11-21
100031959-12-03ghi
10003CdefghijkM1986-08-28
100041954-05-01jkl
10004Defgh    M1986-12-01
```

Please suggest me how to do in SSIS or SQL server

Thanks

Comment: What is a "package"?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-ssis-packages?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trick the system.  Generate the nested output of both queries in a single query, like this:

```
select 
    Cast(emp_no AS Char(5)) + Convert(Char(10), birth_date, 120) + 
    CAST(first_name as CHAR(10)) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
    Cast(emp_no AS Char(5)) + CAST(last_name as CHAR(9)) + 
    gender + Convert(Char(10), hire_date, 120) 
from employees
where emp_no in (10001,10002,10003,10004);
```

Comment: Hi Vergil,
We need data into 8 rows.. 1st row from 1st statement and 2nd row from 2nd statement, 3rd row from 1st statement and 4th row from 2nd statement ....so on

Comment: That's what this does. The `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` in the `SELECT` statement adds a Windows line break into the input text. Even though it only outputs one field, in a .txt file it outputs as two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use a UNION ALL query in your data source to get a single-column resultset that looks the way you want it, and then just do a straight dataflow to your flat file destination.

Psuedo-code query:

```
SELECT {Query #1 Concatenated into one column, with added "SortBy" column = 1}
UNION ALL {Query #2 Concatenated into one column, with added "SortBy" column = 2}
ORDER BY emp_no, SortBy
```

Obviously don't map the "SortBy" column to your Destination so it won't show up in the flat file.

Comment: Hi Alleman, In 1st statement have 3 columns and in 2nd statement we have 4. I think it's not possible to do union all.
I need result 1 row from 1st statement and 1 row from 2nd statement and so on

Comment: Thank you for your time and valuable suggestion/Direction.  It is Working

Comment: @Nadim I thought it was pretty clear that I was suggesting that you concatenate the columns into one.   That way it IS possible to do a UNION ALL.